# Есть ли тут лишняя запятая? И где?

Tags: пунктуация

*Их разговор о том, что ты все-таки переедешь, когда поступишь в колледж, испортил мое настроение.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все запятые на месте. Одна открывает первое придаточное, вторая второе, а третья закрывает оба.